# Spring Java Config: Tomcat deploy without web.xml

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin, spring-java-config

I built a java configured Spring MVC application without any XML. I can deploy and start the application on my laptop without any problems. But as soon as I try to deploy my application on my testserver (tomcat 7), I receive following message:

```
HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource (/[application context]/) is not available.
```

I build my applications using the Eclipse Maven plugin. Is it possible to deploy the application without the web.xml and if not, which is the basic web.xml I really need?

Maven WAR Plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

WebAppInitializer:

```
@Order(value = 1)
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { HibernateConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class, HibernateDaoConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[]{};
    }
}
```

Update: catalina.out

```
Feb 3, 2014 4:18:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/[appname]] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 3, 2014 4:18:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/[appname]]
Feb 3, 2014 4:18:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive [appname].war
```

Comment: What are your startup logs showing?

Comment: Just "INFO: Deploying web application archive [appname].war" in catalina.out

Comment: Change Spring logging to a DEBUG and check.

Comment: Please check update: But I still do not get more information.

Comment: How does the server used in Eclipse differ from the test server? Is it the same tomcat version?

Comment: No the test server uses tomcat6. As soon as I am using following goal to run my application locally, I am facing the same problem like on the server. (org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat6-maven-plugin:2.1:run). So it seems that the problem is the tomcat version. (Must be tomcat7) I will check this and post my solution.

Comment: Tomcat6 doesn't support Java config. You need a recent version of Tomcat 7 to support that. Early versios of Tomcat 7 had problems with Java config.

Answer (score 1):

If this still isn't solved, it is possibly due to the Servlet version.  The Servlet 3.x API is required to have the possibility to configure a java web application by writing a java class instead of having a web.xml file inside the WEB-INF folder.

see [here](http://ralf.schaeftlein.de/2012/10/01/replacing-web-xml-with-java-based-configuration-for-servlet-3-x-webapplications/) for a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

I'd upgrade to the latest Tomcat version and see if that works (to isolate your issue). There are many issues with using the new spring features (ex: java config, etc.) with older Tocmat servers. For example, see: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html

> > Mapping to '/' under Tomcat
> >
> > Apache Tomcat maps its internal DefaultServlet to "/", and on Tomcat versions <= 7.0.14, this >>servlet mapping cannot be overridden programmatically. 7.0.15 fixes this issue. Overriding the "/" >>servlet mapping has also been tested successfully under GlassFish 3.1.