# Spring JavaConfig and Tomcat 8

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a Spring 4 web application (webapp-module.war) working and running locally in eclipse using Java 8, tomcat 8 and JavaConfig (no web.xml):

[image]

But when I deploy to tomcat 8 (same version I am using locally in eclipse) on a remote Ubuntu server I get:

[image]

I verified host and port which are correct. There is no error in the log (/var/lib/tomcat8/logs/catalina.out)

```
Jun 21, 2016 10:32:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig undeploy
INFO: Undeploying context [/webapp-module]
Jun 21, 2016 10:32:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/webapp-module.war
Jun 21, 2016 10:32:46 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 21, 2016 10:32:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/webapp-module.war has finished in 1,870 ms
root@vmi63860:/var/lib/tomcat8/logs#
```

The access log contains:

```
root@vmi63860:/var/log/tomcat8# cat localhost_access_log.2016-06-22.txt 
xx.xxx.xxx.xx - - [22/Jun/2016:22:36:00 +0200] "GET /webapp-module/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1040
xx.xxx.xxx.xx - - [22/Jun/2016:22:36:00 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1034
xx.xxx.xxx.xx - - [22/Jun/2016:22:36:50 +0200] "GET /webapp-module/hello HTTP/1.1" 404 1050
```

Where xx.xxx.xxx.xx is the IP of my local machine from where I try to access the web app in my browser.

I took a look at:
[Spring Java Config: Tomcat deploy without web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529577/spring-java-config-tomcat-deploy-without-web-xml) but it does not really provide a solution.

Details on my project below:

**Sources**

[image]

**Config.java**

```
@Configuration // Marks this class as configuration
// Specifies which package to scan
@ComponentScan("com.samples")
// Enables Spring's annotations
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config {

  @Bean
  public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
  }

}
```

**WebInitializer.java**

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(Config.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

    Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

  }

}
```

**HelloController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String home() {
    return "index";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/hello")
  public String showhello(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
    return "hello";
  }

}
```

Comment: Check if a hit is being got inside **localhost_access_log.*.txt** inside tomcat **logs** folder

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I updated the question with the content from the most recent access log on the server after I tried to access the web app from my browser. Does not show any errors though

Comment: They might look like silly questions, but is the war file named webapp-module? I suppose you're running it in a tomcat instance too while in eclipse, do the tomcat versions match?

Comment: Yes to all your questions, see updated post. Strange that no errors are reported anywhere since it clearly fails to access it on the server from my browser

Comment: I think each acess log line shows a 404 error. If you put a dummy `test.jsp` in `webapp` do you see it in `/webapp-module/test.jsp` ? and if not, in `/test.jsp` ?

Comment: Could you confirm what is context root setup for this application. you can get it from application.xml file

Comment: Can you check the Tomcat Manager app (`/manager`) on the remote server? If so, does your app, `/webapp-module`, show up there as having been deployed? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38794114/639520 if you can't access `/manager`

Comment: How did you build the jar? Are all files in it? Try to open it as zip to verify the contents.

Comment: Can you post your application log file ? It could be you have errors on startup so the app has never started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry previously I was too hasty

It seems that spring context is not at all loaded.

I guess the problem is in this piece of code:

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(Config.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

    Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

  }

}
```

You used `ctx.register(Config.class);`

In any case I always used this kind of initialization:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.scan("com.spring");
        rootContext.setConfigLocations(new String[]{"com.spring.config.WebAppContextConfig", "com.spring.config.AppConfig"});
        // Manages the lifecycle of the root application context
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Declare dispatcher servlet. Handles requests into the application
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }

}
```

As you can see I used `rootContext.setConfigLocations` in order to specify where to find the spring configuration classes

In any case [Here](https://github.com/angeloimm/stackoverflow/tree/master/SpringStack) you can find a working sample I successfully deployed it on tomcat 8.0.39 and 8.5.4

Hope it's useful

Angelo

Comment: Could you include the context.xml in the example?

Comment: @sonance207 I have no context.xml file in this example... I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was not doing anything wrong in code. Tomcat server is configured to use strict servlet compliance.

```
org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=true
```

This setting affects multiple other properties ([see here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html#Specifications)). One of them is "The resourceOnlyServlets attribute of any Context element". Setting this value to "jsp" in application's context.xml solved the problem.

> Comma separated list of Servlet names (as used in /WEB-INF/web.xml) that expect a resource to be present. Ensures that welcome files associated with Servlets that expect a resource to be present (such as the JSP Servlet) are not used when there is no resource present. This prevents issues caused by the clarification of welcome file mapping in section 10.10 of the Servlet 3.0 specification. If the org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE system property is set to true, the default value of this attribute will be the empty string, else the default value will be jsp.

Answer (score -1):

Add `finalName` as `ROOT` in your `pom.xml`. This will create ROOT.war file in your target folder.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
<!--All plugins are here -->
        </plugins>
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
    </build>
```

After that if you deploy ROOT.war file in your tomcat. Then your accessing url will be 
http://localhost:8080

Hope it will solve your issue.

For further checking, please go through http://localhost:8080/manager/html
it will call for username and password. Check that is set or not.

If not set, please go through this tutorial: [Can't access Tomcat 8 Manager App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38469496) as suggested by [E-Riz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/639520/e-riz)

For full example, go through this tutorial: http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-helloworld-tutorial-annotation-javaconfig-full-example/

Comment: I have tried the websystique example. It runs on tomcat / Win 10 development machine but does work on tomcat /RHL server. Both have TC 8.0.18.
PS: Our organization policy does not allow manager app for security reasons, so that's not an option. :(

Comment: @zendu For server deployment, manager app is not allowed. Have you tried with ROOT.war for server? Please check. If error exists, please share the log file.