# Can't access Tomcat 8 Manager App

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I've just set up Tomcat 8 on an Ubuntu 14.04 VM and I'm not able to access the Manager App at `http://[hostname]:8080/manager/html` from my browser. I get a "403 Access Denied" error as soon as I click on it. I am running Tomcat as a service defined in a config file in `/etc/init.d/tomcat8-dev`. The error message indicates that Tomcat is set up to be accessible only from localhost initially, but as it is a hosted VM I'm not able to run a browser on it.

I have set up a user in the `tomcat-users.xml` file as several people have recommended. However, I am not prompted to provide the credentials for that user, and I can't find any kind of login button on the default page. That file currently looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-status"/>

    <user username="(redacted)" password="(redacted)" 
        roles="manager-gui,manager-jmx,manager-status,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

After reading the Tomcat documentation page [here](http://192.81.128.253:8080/docs/manager-howto.html), I have also tried adding `<Valve />` tags into `context.xml` that look something like this:

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false"
    docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127\.0\.0\.1" />
    <!--Another valve for my local machine's IP-->

</Context>
```

However, as soon as I set `privileged="true"`, I get a blank white page when I connect to the server with my browser regardless of the valves I provide afterwards.

I restart my service with `sudo service tomcat8-dev restart` whenever I make changes.

Other things I have tried based on posts I read here and on other sites:

- Various configurations of roles for my tomcat user
- Adding `address="0.0.0.0"` to `server.xml` inside the `<Connector />` tag
- Using `initctl` instead of setting up a service based on the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04), which doesn't load the default page on my server for some reason
- Trying different browsers, and disabling my popup blocker

Nothing I've tried works. Please let me know if you would like more details about my situation. Any suggestions?

**Edit:** The problem was that I was editing the wrong `context.xml` file. The correct file is in `tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF`. I had incorrectly been making changes to `tomcat/conf/context.xml`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

AFAIK Tomcat blocks access to the Manager App (manager/html) for all hosts but localhost in its default configuration.

To be able to access the manager GUI with http://[hostname]:8080/manager/html, configure this in the configuration files *server.xml* and the *context.xml* of the manager application:

**Step 1:** In [tomcat-install-dir]/conf/server.xml edit the *Connector* element and add your IP as well as useIPVHosts="true", i.e.:

```xml
<Connector port="9009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="9443" 
           address="192.168.0.9" useIPVHosts="true" />
```

`address="0.0.0.0"` is probably not what you want to insert here, as it exposes the manager GUI to all machines on the network.

**Step 2:** In [tomcat-install-dir]/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml, edit the *Valve* element and add your IP:

```xml
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true">

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
           allow="192\.168\.0\.9|127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
</Context>
```

From [Tomcat 8 context documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html)

> **privileged** : Set to true to allow this context to use container
>   servlets, like the manager servlet.
>
> **antiResourceLocking** : If true, Tomcat will prevent any file locking. This will significantly impact startup time of applications,
>   but allows full webapp hot deploy and undeploy on platforms or
>   configurations where file locking can occur

Note, that I don't add another Valve element as you mentioned in the list of things you tried but instead I edit the existing one and just add my IP (192.168.0.9).

**Step 3:** Restart Tomcat and you should be able to access the manager GUI with localhost / 127.0.0.1 as well as with your hostname / IP.

---

#### NOTE

Regarding your *tomcat-users.xml*, the [Tomcat Manager HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access) states:

> It is recommended to never grant the manager-script or manager-jmx
>   roles to users that have the manager-gui role.

So you might want to introduce two users in your *tomcat-users.xml*, i.e.:

```xml
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <user username="alice" password="whatever" roles="manager-script,manager-jmx"/>
  <user username="bob" password="whatever" roles="manager-gui,manager-status"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It turns out I was editing the wrong context.xml file. I edited the details into the original question.

Comment: @ecliptica Glad to hear it works for you now - you're welcome.

Comment: @ronan Quillevere I am facing same issue with tomcat9+java9, as suggest added <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" address="0.0.0.0" useIPVHosts="true" /> . Also added the mentioned changes in webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml,,  but didn't work. Please suggest

Comment: I did the changes suggested in the answer, with Tomcat9, but still can't run the Manager app from any browser, which @GouthamNithyananda is also experiencing

Comment: Replaced hostname with IP Address of Vagrant host. It works

Answer (score 5):

You can simply do like if you want to access manager app on all machines. Go to {Tomcat_install_DIR}/webapps/manager/META-INF/ and edit context.xml put

```xml
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
 <!--
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" 
  allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
  -->
</Context>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change:

```
docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager"
```

to:

```
docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/manager"
```

This is because you don't use Tomcat as distributed from upstream but the one which comes with Ubuntu.

Comment: which file to change?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help for all of you because its work for me.

Here I'm using Apache tomcat 8:

```
root@akash-LIFEBOOK-A555:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.20/bin# ./version.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.20
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.20
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.20/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /DATA/jre1.8.0_131/
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.20/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.20/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
Server built:   Aug 2 2017 21:35:49 UTC
Server number:  8.5.20.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     4.4.0-98-generic
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_131-b11
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Edit tomcat-user.xml and added the roles and users

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,manager-status,manager-script,manager-jmx,admin-gui"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me addition to put admin user with manager roles in tomcat-users.xml, I MUST also modify 2 /META-INF/context.xml files of manager and host-manager apps under /webapps, with the following:
127 -> \d+
Thus will make any out-side pcs' browser access to its manager-site[image: change 127 localhost IP to any vistors' IP]

Answer (score 0):

I also fetched same issue and what i did first added role user and passowrd in config/tomcat-users.xml then allowed my public ip in webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml 
there initially local ip 127 added for use manager from same machine. there add your ip

Comment: It sounds like you solved the problem... can we turn it into a set of steps in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Update the 'apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xlm file. uncomment the Value tag. and restart server

context.xml  file

```
Before : 

<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true">
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
     allow="192\.168\.0\.9|127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
</Context>

After change :

<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
</Context>

for auto deployment: go to 'apache-tomcat-8.5.5\conf\context.xml' and add antiResourceLocking="true" in 'Context' tag
```