# Tomcat 8 - Can't access manager app

Tags: java, tomcat

When I try to access the manager app on my Tomcat server I run into HTTP 404 status:

> The requested resource is not available.

To gain access to the manager app I did the following:

Edited the `[TOMCAT_HOME]/conf/tomcat-users.xml` and created a new user:

```xml
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd" version="1.0">
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Edited the `[TOMCAT_HOME]/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml` and allowed access from anywhere:

```xml
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <!--<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
     allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />-->
</Context>
```

Then I restarted my Tomcat server. I can enter the `http://server_domain_or_IP:8080` page but when I click on the link to the manager webapp, I'm faced with the HTTP 404 status.

Comment: Dis you check in the log, if there is some errors or warnings?

Comment: I went to [TOMCAT_HOME]/logs and opened the manager.2017-02-07.log. It's empty.

Comment: No, I'm running the tomcat server on my droplet on DigitalOcean.

Comment: In the [TOMCAT_HOME]/webapps I have docs, examples, host-manager, manager and ROOT.

Comment: Did you read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469496/cant-access-tomcat-8-manager-app ?

Comment: Yes but I'm not getting HTTP 403 status. Also, the solution does not apply to me. I have edited the correct context.xml.

Comment: HTTP 403 or HTTP 404 error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135118/discussion-between-milaci-and-richard-silvertass).