# Spring Maven + IntelliJ and 404

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

So, today I finally decided to try out IntelliJ IDEA.

After setting up everything I tried to make a VERY simple Spring webMVC
Project.

And as this is a Spring application, I'm at a point where I don't
have any errors or warnings but just 404 page when I run my project...

Tomcat 9 runs without any warnings or errors and Java seem also
to have no problems. Running will open a browser with the way way too common 404 - resource not found error.

#### SpringTest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.clomez</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

#### HomeController

```
package com.clomez.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 * Created by Clomez-admin on 14.4.2017.
 */

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home(){

        return "home";
    }
}
```

#### WebInit.class

```
package com.clomez.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

/**
 * Created by Clomez-admin on 14.4.2017.
 */

@Configuration
public class WebInit  extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{RootConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

RootConf.class

```
package com.clomez.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * Created by Clomez-admin on 14.4.2017.
 */

@Configuration
public class RootConfig {
}
```

WebConfig.class

```
package com.clomez.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

/**
 * Created by Clomez-admin on 14.4.2017.
 */

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.clomez")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver(){

        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Please can anybody help me with this? After two months I mostly feel like getting a cancer from this Spring framework thing, but I don't have choice if I want to complete my degree.

Tomcat runs smoothly, there aren't any errors or warnings in the editor, and it brings up a browser with 404 - home.jsp not found.

Comment: do you have a home.jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got your code running on Wildfly 10 and after I dropped a home.jsp into my `/src/main/webapp/` directory I was served its content.

```
09:55:10,036 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
09:55:10,105 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.13.SP1 20160303-1204 for context '/SpringTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
09:55:10,808 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
09:55:10,809 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
09:55:10,818 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Apr 14 09:55:10 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
09:55:10,852 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Registering annotated classes: [class com.clomez.config.RootConfig]
09:55:10,962 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
09:55:11,018 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 209 ms
09:55:11,027 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
09:55:11,027 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
09:55:11,030 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Apr 14 09:55:11 EDT 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
09:55:11,030 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Registering annotated classes: [class com.clomez.config.WebConfig]
09:55:11,116 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
09:55:11,270 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.clomez.controller.HomeController.home()
09:55:11,481 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
09:55:11,539 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Apr 14 09:55:11 EDT 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
09:55:11,615 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 588 ms
09:55:11,616 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /SpringTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
09:55:11,635 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "SpringTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "SpringTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
```

When you return `"home"` in your `HomeController`, the `InternalResourceViewResolver` you set up in your `WebConfig` is used to resolve jsps against the internals or your WAR (where the default base of your war file had `/src/main/webapp` added to it by maven).

Edit:

And just to confirm for you, I downloaded Tomcat 9.0.0.M19 and I am receiving a 404 when I request `http://localhost:8080/SpringTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/`. I'll give 8 a quick whirl.

Edit 2:

Tomcat 8.5.13 returns a 404 as well. . . . Both 8.5 and 9 support the Servlet 3 spec, but I'm guessing that there's a wrinkle in there somewhere when it collides with these newer Spring features. I found [Spring Java Config: Tomcat deploy without web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529577/spring-java-config-tomcat-deploy-without-web-xml) and http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html notes that:

> Mapping to '/' under Tomcat
>
> Apache Tomcat maps its internal DefaultServlet to "/", and on Tomcat versions <= 7.0.14, this servlet mapping cannot be overridden programmatically. 7.0.15 fixes this issue. Overriding the "/" servlet mapping has also been tested successfully under GlassFish 3.1.

I did try changing your mapping from `/` to `/home` and Tomcat still wasn't happy (Wildfly was).

More edits to come if I find anything.

Edit 3:

Umm. Well, I'm a bit gobsmacked. Tested with Tomcat 9, instead of requesting `http://localhost:8080/SpringTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/` try going to `http://localhost:8080/SpringTest/`. With a `home.jsp`, as above, your code works!

Edit 4 (sigh):

For completeness and perhaps just because I'm using Eclipse, I had to add 2 bits of maven build plugin configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I wouldn't expect these to affect you now if they haven't previously.